# Should we reopen a "too broad" question when the OP has a solution for it?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

In the review queue for reopening closed questions, I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52001503/336648), which appears to be correctly closed as *too broad*.

The edit added after closing however, is the following:

> UPDATE:
>   I solve this problem and i want to share the answer because solution of this is hard to find out, but nothing is in my hand because people mark this question as too broad.

Is this a legitimate reason for reopening a question, even if it is initially too broad? I can't quite make up my mind about whether I think the question could be helpful to others or not.

Comment: If the OP wants to share their solution, a blog post would be a better option. I say leave it closed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the fact that the OP says that they have "the answer" doesn't automatically make the question fit for Stack Overflow.

Read the question **disregarding that update**.

Do you consider it too broad? If the answer is "yes", click on *Leave Closed*. You could add a comment encouraging the question author to edit their question so it's no longer *too broad*, but that's up to you.

Do you disagree with the original close voters and think that the question is not *too broad*? Click on *Reopen*.

(On that particular question, I would personally choose *Leave Closed*.)